# Dojo2 How to force dojo 2 widget to re-render?

Tags: typescript, dojo2

I am using dojo2 widget. I want to render the widget(VDOM) on form submit.

```
public submitFrom(input: any): void {
    console.log("want to re-render widget after this.");
}
```

In submitFrom I want re-render my dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

Dojo 2 widgetbase has invalidate method, which force the widget to re-render.
Dojo 2 Widgets can invoke invalidate() directly, however a non-widget can only emit an event with: this.emit({ type: 'invalidate' })

```
public submitFrom(input: any): void {
  console.log("want to re-render widget after this.");
  // force the widget to re-render
  this.invalidate();
}
```

For non-widget need to do as follows:-

```
public submitForm(): void {
    this.emit({ type: 'invalidate' });
}
```

Comment: is the internal state of the widget i.e. properties of the widget are changing when you submit a form? If so, whatever the approach that you have taken is valid.

Comment: It's not actually the form submit but my requirement was to fore the widget to re-render.

Comment: invalidate is used when the internal state of the widget is changed for ex: if there was a textbox value 10 and upon submitting the form value got changed to 20 and you want to show the new value, you can use invalidate method. If the values are not changed then you need to think of other way. invalidate does serve the purpose you are looking for but I feel it's not the right way to use it. I'm going by the definition of invalidate from dojo.